# Is it okay to write to a file and read it in a different program simultaneously

Tags: python, io, standards

This is mostly a sanity check, but I'm writing a python program to run in the background on boot and control two motors and two heaters. It determines what to do by checking a settings file every second (using Asyncio). A second program can be run by the user to modify the pickled settings file.

If this were to run for a long period of time (12+ hours), is this the best way to do it? I'm well versed in general coding principles, but not specifically Python.

Comment: Content of the question is not related to the subject. Regarding to the subject, "Yes, writing to a file from only one process and reading it from multiple processes is okay and won't cause race conditions". Regarding to "what is the best way" part, I would not read the configuration file after boot, instead, **manually** trigger the process on configuration change, like `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`. Manually updating the file helps user make multiple changes and have a chance to check for syntax errors etc. before actually enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay for that program that reads the file, but if multiple programs can edit the same file, You might encounter some issues and they might corrupt the file...

Say both `program_1` and `program_2` can edit the same file. The problem is that you wouldn't be editing the file directly like its a global variable. You will be reading it into some variables, making changes in the variables, and then overwriting the file with the new settings.

### Now consider the following scenario:

1. `program_1` Reads the file.
2. `program_2` Reads the file.
3. `program_1` makes some changes to some data.
4. `program_2` makes some changes to other data.
5. `program_1` rewrites the file with the new content.
6. `program_2` rewrites the file with the new content.

in the above scenario, the changes made by `program_1` was accidentally removed by `program_2` because they both attempted to make changes at the same time.

### Simple solution

Make sure each program locks the file before starting to read and edit. And wait for it to be unlocked if it was already locked by the other program.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the second program is writing the file, but this is pretty risky. The first program could try to read the file while the second program is in the middle of writing, and get a truncated file. Or the second program could modify the file while the first program is in the middle of reading, and the first program will get half old data and half new data.

If you want to update a file atomically on Unix, the second program should write to a temporary file, and then rename the temporary file to the original file. Then, the first program will always see a complete stable file.

If your config file is small, you can probably get away with writing the file directly, at least most of the time, but then you'll hit a weird non-reproducible bug every so often.

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24395/rewrite-existing-file-so-that-it-gets-replaced-by-new-version-atomically-only-o) for more information on atomically updating files.